# Webpack doesn't resolve properly my alias

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I am trying to have a namespace for my app to work as a module, and import my components using this namespace and limit the use of relative path.

Although, even though I followed the webpack documentation for alias here: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias
I can't make it to work.

This is how my resolve object looks like:

```
resolve: {
  root: path.resolve(__dirname),
  alias: {
    myApp: './src',
  },
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.json', '.jsx']
}
```

`path.resolve(__dirname)` resolves `/Users/Alex/Workspace/MyAppName/ui/`

I import my file that way in the file `/Users/Alex/Workspace/MyAppName/ui/src/components/Header/index.jsx`:

```
import { myMethod } from 'myApp/utils/myUtils';
```

I get the following error during the build:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/Header/index.jsx
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'myApp/utils/myUtils' in /Users/Alex/Workspace/MyAppName/ui/src/components/Header
 @ ./src/components/Header/index.jsx 33:19-56
```

I also tried with `modulesDirectories` but it doesn't work either.

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: And you try to resolve the path directly in the alias like: `myApp: path.resolve( __dirname, 'src' )`

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work... same error.

Comment: what about `alias: { myApp: 'src' }` that's what I have in my setup.

Comment: and you for sure have `src/utils/myUtils.js` or `src/utils/myUtils/index.js` ?

Comment: I have tried `src` and doesn't work either. The file name is `myUtils.js` but it's supposed to resolve it as per the `extensions` property.

Comment: In electron-react-boilerplate `alias: { '@components': 'components' }` worked for me even though my `components` directory was nested in `src`. Weird.

Answer (score 26):

Resolving the alias to the absolute path should do the trick:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    myApp: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  },
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
}
```

Check this [webpack resolve alias gist](https://gist.github.com/dreyescat/30a8afc8b77a6e208dd6767f1868d81b) with a simple example.

Another solution to limit the number of relative paths is to add your `./src` folder as [root](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root) instead of aliasing it:

```
resolve: {
  root: [path.resolve('./src')],
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
}
```

Then you will be able to require all folders inside `./src` as if they where modules. For example, assuming you have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── node_modules
├── src
│   ├── components
│   └── utils
```

you would be able to import from `components` and `utils` like this:

```
import Header from 'components/Header';
import { myMethod } from 'utils/myUtils';
```

Something like having an alias for each folder inside `./src`.

Comment: I've also tried this and I can't get it to work. It creates the build, but keep throwing this error. Looks like my issue is somewhere else...

Comment: This seems to be invalid solution in 2023

Answer (score 7):

Most of the time it depends on your project folder structure. If your webpack file is inside a folder then make sure you handle it accordingly

```
.
├── node_modules
├── src
│   ├── components
│   └── config/webpack.config.js
```

```
modules.exports = {
 resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      Components: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components/'),
    }
  },
  ...
  resolve: {
    ...
  }
}
```

Also it often happens that we name our folder as "source" but use "src" in path.

> Darn! that copy paste has taken alot of my debug time

Hope this helps someone who is facing such issues due to the above reasons.

Comment: this is a clear explanation! the alias config depends on where the webpack config is located in the folder structure. thanks for the `.../`

Answer (score 6):

This might be obvious to many but if you, like me, have spent too much time trying to figure out why it suddenly does not work when moving from Windows or Mac to Linux then check casing in the paths...

Me and everyone else on the project are using Windows or Mac but at home I dual boot ubuntu which I enjoy using. On cloning our code and running webpack i got a whole lot of `Cannot resolve module...` errors. I spent more time than I'd like to admit searching for some obscure error in node, npm, webpack or anything until I noticed the paths of the failing modules were something like `@app/Shared/settings.js` and the require was `require('@app/shared/settings')`. Windows doesn't care so everything was fine all until I started working on linux. As it turned out problem was not with webpack, node or anything else so that's probably why I didn't find anyone suggesting that this could be the problem.

Hope this saves some time for someone. Or maybe I'm just dumb, I don't know.

Comment: In short: some OSes/filesystems are case-sensitive so this issue is not due to `resolve.alias` but rather how files are looked up on the filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error. Finnaly I found the problem was that I wrote `resolve` twice. And the second `resolve` override the previous one.
My code is like this:

```
modules.exports = {
 resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      Components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
    }
  },
  ...
  resolve: {
    ...
  }
}
```

More help can be found in [Webpack Doc](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/)

Answer (score 0):

I use without next syntax :

```
resolve: {
        alias: {
            Data:  __dirname + '/src/data'
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']

    }

import points from 'Data/points.json';
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to alias `mobx`, so that any import of `mobx` would always return the same instance, regardless of whether the import call was from my main app, or from within one of the libraries it used.

At first I had this:

```
webpackConfig.resolve.alias = {
    mobx: path.resolve(root, "node_modules", "mobx"),
};
```

However, this only forced imports of `mobx` from my app's own code to use the alias.

To have it work for the library's import calls as well, I had to do:

```
webpackConfig.resolve.alias = {
    mobx: path.resolve(root, "node_modules", "mobx"),
    "LIBRARY_X/node_modules/mobx": path.resolve(root, "node_modules", "mobx"),
};
```

It's odd, because I'm pretty sure just having the `mobx` alias used to work for both contexts before, but now it apparently doesn't (Webpack v4.41.2).

Anyway, the above is how I solved it. (In my case, I needed it to prevent two mobx instances from being used as that breaks things, and `LIBRARY_X` was symlinked using npm-link, so I couldn't delete/unify the secondary `mobx` folder itself)

Answer (score 0):

Adding what worked for me since this still pops up first when I search "webpack resolve alias not working" and none of the existing answers worked for me.

My config used the absolute path as [the top voted answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36374591/13771937):

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    myApp: path.resolve(__dirname, '@packageName'),
  },
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
}
```

But it was still throwing the same type of error OP was describing. I'm primarily working in a monorepo and I realized it was because webpack was trying to resolve an import on a dependency (a sibling package within the monorepo) that didn't exist as a dependency of the source package.

Essentially, I had `packageA` referencing `packageB`. `packageB` was importing `packageC` (all 3 being sibling packages in the monorepo). Webpack was trying to resolve `packageC` using `packageA` as the resolution (ie `packageA/node_modules/packageC`), but `packageC` is not a direct dependency of `packageA`, but rather a dependency of `packageB`, which was throwing the error. I found I could just add additional aliases to fix this, something like the following in the webpack config for packageA (depending on your tree structure):

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    @packageB: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@packageB'),
    @packageC: path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'packageB/node_modules/@packageC'),
  },
  extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
}
```

I didn't like the idea of continuously adding resolve.aliases whenever weird situations came up, so I ended up switching all my `resolve.alias` references to calls to [NormalModuleReplacement](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/) as I was able to define a single callback to deal with all situations (and I share the same callback across all webpack configs).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was as simple as writing a wrong directory name.

Usually in the examples it's somethings like:

```
'~': path.resolve(__dirname, "src");
```

But in my project the folder was actually called "app". And it's kindof the same, some projects have "app", others have "src". So double check that the folder you write is the correct one.